# Command to set printing the content of pointer to structure or array in GDB

Tags: gdb

I know how to print the content of the structure or array being pointed by a pointer in gdb . But my question is that whether there exists a command like "info locals" which not only print the address of a pointer which is a local variable in this context but also prints its content (i.e if the pointer is pointing to an array or a structure then it should print its content also).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any built-in way to do this.

However, it would not be too hard to script this using Python.  You can get the selected frame and then iterate over the blocks of the function for that frame, printing the variables in each block in any way you like.

Comment: Hey Tom..thanx for the info. But what if one of the variable is a void pointer?  We then need to typecast and at that moment we wont be having the required typecasting variable's info.

Comment: There's of course no generic way to do that, but if you know which variables need that treatment, it is easy to do from Python.